# How to solve Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to implement the method Bottom Navigation view but when i run my code i get this error

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" on path: DexPathList[

what should i do to solve this problems?

activity_home layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="android:.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehaviour"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/purpleBae"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/home_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle(Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gerobokgoapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    compileOptions {
        incremental true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    //add libraries
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.39.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
}
```

and use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` instead

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix both support and androidx libraries together in the same project, there will surely be conflicts unless you're using Jetpack tool. Migrate your support libraries to androidx

Also References in an Androidx layout file should all be androidx artifacts and not otherwise.

Hence tag like this:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/purpleBae"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/home_menu" />
```

Should be:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
  android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/purpleBae"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/home_menu" />
```

Comment: same answer, please don't replicate my answer @Nidheesh

Comment: You were only mentioned the library implementation. Not the usage of bottom navigation view. The implementation already there in the gradile file.